# Where is the user data stored after decoding it from the token?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, local-storage

Where is the user data stored after decoding it from the token? I'm using react , and the Jwt token is stored in local-storage .

Comment: Are you referring to making a request to the server and fetching user data? Or are you asking how to retrieve the token from local-storage and use it for future request?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery the later one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data is stored in state and not in localstorage due to security issues.